# Use variable for inline style in .html.erb file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, variables, sass, custom-data-attribute

I have a Sass variable, such as:

`$color: #ddd`

I have a view.html.erb file that has a data attribute, such as:

`<%= f.button :button, class: class, data: { "spinner-color": "#ddd"` } %>

I obviously can't access the aforementioned Sass variable in my view (too late in the process). But I want to repeat this color throughout other html files in the DRYest way possible. In other words, I would prefer to use a variable, perhaps a Ruby constant?

Open advice... what's the best way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use string interpolation:

`<%= f.button :button, class: class, data: { 'spinner-color': "'#{COLOR_SPINNER}'" } %>`

Answer (score 0):

I have idea on how to do it but i don't recommend it. From my opinion, SASS variable dry your code pretty well. You can also define constants in helper to keep your other variables clean.